# PHP read XML output as array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm looping through node values in my XML file, but I can't get the output as I need it. Below is the code that I'm working with.

**PHP:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");         
$result = array();
foreach($xml->picture as $item)
{
     $result[]  =  $item->logo;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Current output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => img/a.jpg
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => img/b.jpg
        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => img/c.jpg
        )

    ...
 )
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a.jpg
    [1] => b.jpg
    [2] => c.jpg

    ...
)
```

Comment: I think my answer helped you to solve your problem. You should accept it so that the question will be closed. People will not click on your question if there is not accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out: [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

```
function toArray(SimpleXMLElement $xml) {
    $array = (array)$xml;

    foreach ( array_slice($array, 0) as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value instanceof SimpleXMLElement ) {
            $array[$key] = empty($value) ? NULL : toArray($value);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the number of the loop in the array, your code stays like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");         
$result = array();
$i = 0;//set a variable to loop throw the foreach
foreach($xml->picture as $item)
    {
//assign the variable with the number of the loop in the disired array
         $result[$i]  =  $item->logo;
    }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```